# Translate odata uri to expression

Tags: linq, wcf-data-services, odata, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to use an action filter to translate an Odata uri to a Linq expression. I'm doing this because i'm using the resulting expression to query nonSQL line of business systems. In the WCF web api this was trivial because the translated query was appended as a property of the the request object, as such:

```
var query = (EnumerableQuery)request.Properties["queryToCompose"];
```

That seems to have disappeared. Are there any public api's i can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out the query has changed keys in the request property collection. It also seems that the internal filter that parses the query runs after the custom filters and  thus doesn't add the query value. To get the translated query, call the following inside the controller action.

```
(EnumerableQuery<T>)this.Request.Properties["MS_QueryKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying something similiar.. While not perfect, you can grab the OData expressions directly from the query string and build the LINQ expression manually:

```
var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString( ControllerContext.Request.RequestUri.Query );
var top = queryParams.Get( "$top" );
var skip = queryParams.Get( "$skip" );
var orderby = queryParams.Get( "$orderby" );
```

And the apply that directly to your `IQueryable` or whatever you're using for the filtering. Not nearly as useful, but its a start.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Linq2Rest](https://bitbucket.org/jjrdk/linq2rest). It solves this problem.